# Javascript Rendering Animations on HTML5 DOM from Array. First Run SLOW! Second Run Smooth. How come?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, animation, canvas

I have a question regarding animations via javascript in HTML using DOM. In this case I am using a  with absolute possition and css + jQuery and animate the div.

So when I run through my big array of positions x,y the animation runs very slow. I am running at 100ms (80ms) Interval, but it seems that the rendering is not fast enough and my animations takes longer than 10 seconds...

When re-running the animation it seems that the instructions have been somehow cached ( Rendering ) and my animations runs just perfect.

Then again if I wait for lets say 5 mins, it will be slow again. ( Seems to be low level machine code memory  which has been deleted, because it was not used again? )

I just cant figure out how to let my animation run smooth, if its executed the first time.
I tried fabric.js to render animations... Same problem. At the first run its slow. Second run and following are smooth.

```
function render_mouse()
 {
     if(play_pos < mousefile_length)
         {
            $('.mouse').remove();
            $("body").append(
            $('<div id="mouse" class="mouse"></div>')
            .css('position', 'absolute')
            .css('top', play_mousefile[play_pos+1] + 'px')
            .css('left', play_mousefile[play_pos] + 'px')
            .css('width', mousesize)
            .css('height', mousesize)
            .css('background-image', 'url(images/cursor.png')
                    );
            play_pos = play_pos +2;
            }
    else {
        clearInterval(play_mousetimer);
         }
   }

UPDATED:
 $('#mouse').animate({
                 left: rec_mousefile[play_pos]+"px",
                 top : rec_mousefile[play_pos+1]+"px"
                 },80);
```

Comment: Posting your code here would help localizing the problem

Comment: Post code.  As of now, my best guess is that you're attempting to rasterize images in real time instead of using a sprite.

Comment: Here is the function rendering the mouse : http://pastebin.com/8gswL79R I replaced remove by animate x,y pos. But still same issues

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PtuwrfRB newer version using jQuery animate.

Comment: Part of the reason the original code is so slow, is because you remove and insert the DIV each time. IIRC, this would cause a reflow every time you did it.

Comment: Funnily enough, I'm running into exactly the same problem, but I'm adding CSS3 animation classes to elements, rather than using JQuery .animate(). 
As GopherKhan suggests, I "cache" the reference, .clone() the element, attach animation classes, add it to the DOM, and .remove() when it's done.
It runs like soggy treacle in the first instance, and like wet butter thereafter. 
I thought it was a reflow issue too, but that doesn't account for how slow the animation runs the first time. Perhaps it has something to do with how the browser initialises CSS? 
In which browser did you find the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation would be faster if you didn't do so many operations on the mouse div every time.

Basically, append the mouse to the dom once, with all the CSS needed for the initial render, cache the reference to the appended element, and then manipulate ONLY the css properties necessary for the animation.

By keeping the element in the dom, rather than removing and re-appending each time, you should see a bit of a performance increase. Further, saving a reference to the appended element will prevent you from having to re-query the dom before giving another update.

The animation should always be a bit faster on a second run due to caching, but these optimizations should help the initial run at least a bit.

** edit in response to comment **

You could cache the reference to the mouse div outside the function, or hang it off the render function itself, a la:

var mouseDiv = $('#mouse');

```
function render_mouse()
{
    if(mousefile_length > play_pos)
                {
                 mouseDiv.animate({
                 left: rec_mousefile[play_pos]+"px",
                 top : rec_mousefile[play_pos+1]+"px"
                 },80);

                 play_pos=play_pos+2;
        }
   else {playtimer.stop();}
}
```

or

```
function render_mouse()
{
    // query the first time, and then use the cached version thereafter
    render_mouse.mouse = render_mouse.mouse || $('#mouse');
    if(mousefile_length > play_pos)
                {
                 render_mouse.mouse.animate({
                 left: rec_mousefile[play_pos]+"px",
                 top : rec_mousefile[play_pos+1]+"px"
                 },80);

                 play_pos=play_pos+2;
        }
   else {playtimer.stop();}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have posted the updated code in pastebin. Its using animate. I am doing like you said here. Still it is  slow when executing it for the first time. Second,Third etc. run smooth rendering.

Comment: Gotcha. You could still cached a reference to the mouse div outside the function, or hang it off the function itself, so that you don't have to use $('#mouse') to select it each time. I'll post a code sample.

Comment: Thanks again. I updated my code like you said. Still having the performance issue. You said " The animation should always be a bit faster on a second run due to caching, but these optimizations should help the initial run at least a bit." Is it possible to somehow pre-cache the animations? I really need it to be as fast as the second run.

Comment: I guess it's possible to try and run the animation first within a hidden div. Say, visibility:hidden rather than display:none. That will still make the containing element take up space in the dom (display:none essentially takes it out of the flow). I'm guessing most browsers would be smart enough that this trick wouldn't work, but it's worth a shot. Alternatively, you could try positioning the mouse off the screen, animate it, and then place it back in its proper position for the actual animation.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried this, but does not have effect on the execution speed. Seems not to be possible to solve this problem.

Comment: You tried the offscreen option as well? What type of browser(s) are you targeting? If you're doing this in Chrome or recent firefox, you could look into css translations instead. Using translate3d might be a bit more reliable than the raw javascript animation.

Comment: Hi, Yes I did. I am targeting all modern browsers Firefox,Chrome,IE. I already used CSS3 translation/transform since it should give me hardware acceleration. This method is not fast if you want to execute many single rendering commands. It is useful if you want to render one big animation with one execution. For myself I have found a solution via CSS. But thanks !